# How can I iterate over an element in an array but not move from the index until a condition is fulfill?

Tags: javascript

Hi fam happy Valentine's.
I'm not looking for a code solution but some insights about how could I go about iterating over an array let's call it array = [1, 1, 1], and not moving to the next element in the array until a condition is fulfilled. For example I want to start at index 0 and only go to the next index (1) after the value of such index is (modified/changed) to be greater than the value of the index before it. At 0 index we have the value 1, I want before moving to index 1 to change the value of index 1 to be greater then the value of index 0. Something like this if we have array = [1, 1, 1] I want to iterate over the array, start at 0 index. Compare if the value of 0 index is greater or equal than the value of index 1 (the next index) If so than add 1 to the value of index 1 until that value is greater than the value of index 0. First iteration we get array = [1, 2, 1].
Next iteration we get array = [1, 2, 3].

At this point I have tried to iterate over the array with a for loop grab each element, compare and add 1 to the element but when I get to the last element it does not add anything since I am at the end of the array and there is no item to loop over. I get array = [1, 2, 2] Please help fam. This is what I have so far.

```
     // array 
     const array = [1, 1, 1]
    
    // iterating over array
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // compare
        if (array[i] >= array[i + 1]) {
            // increase next number by 1
            array[i + 1] += 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `while` instead of `if` to keep adding 1 until the condition is no longer met?  Or make the operation `array[i + 1] = array[i] + 1`

Comment: Oh sweet!!! I will try that for sure. Thank you so much for the fast replay @James.

Comment: you can use **for-loop** all you need is to move the **increment statement** to the **else condition** :  `for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ) {  ....  else { i++; }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start from index `1`, because you can not change the value at index `0` because of the missing previous value.

Inside the loop increment the value until it is greater than the value at the last index.

```js
const array = [1, 1, 1]

for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    while (array[i] <= array[i - 1]) array[i]++;
}

console.log(array);
```

If you don't want to iterate for the increment, you could update the value directly.

```js
const array = [1.2, 1, 1]

for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] <= array[i - 1]) array[i] = Math.floor(array[i - 1] + 1);
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thank you Nina, it was all part of a bigger problem but your for loop plus the while condition did it for me. Thank you a lot!!! Your way helped me avoid getting to the end of the loop and not having more values to compare. I totally missed the fact I could start at index 1 and compare with the item before as I move over in the iteration. You Rock!!! Thank you Again!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Happy Valentines!**

Let's look at what may be causing your array to return [1,2,2]. Good practice (And a bit tedious) is to follow along your inputs and see item by item how your array gets manipulated.

- input: [1,1,1]
- First Pass: [1,1,1], changes to [1,2,1]
- Second Pass:[1,2,1] changes to [1,2,2]

You may have noticed the undesired behaviour happens on the second pass. It's because you're adding 1 to the value and not incrementing based on the index you're on.

Now.. lets get to fixing!

If we assume your input is always [1,1,1] (**ASSUMPTIONS MATTER :)** )
you can simply change array.

```html
            array[i + 1] += 1 to array[i+1] += array[i]
```

If you're looking for a more comprehensive approach where you can take any array input, sort and display an incrementing array -- that's a little further ahead! Focus on the fundamentals :)